# Make entire div clickable for WordPress posts, not just the title?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Currently, only the `h1` gets linked to the post. I would like the entire div `post-info` to be clickable.

I've been working with this, but for some reason nothing changes. The entire div still isn't clickable; only the `h1`.

JS

```
$("article.has-post-thumbnail .post-info").click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    return false;
});
```

HTML

```
<article id="post-1" class="post-1 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-uncategorized">
    <div class="post-info" style="display: none; opacity: 1;">
        <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="/" rel="bookmark">Post Title</a></h1>
        <span class="posted-on">
            <a href="/" rel="bookmark">
                <time class="entry-date published" datetime="2014-08-14T13:02:27+00:00">August 14, 2014</time>
                <time class="updated" datetime="2014-09-24T09:49:19+00:00">September 24, 2014</time>
            </a>
        </span>
    </div>
    <img width="312" height="200" src="http://i.imgur.com/9spxUQe.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" style="opacity: 1;"> 
</article>
```

CSS

```
article {
background: #EE7A1D;
float: left;
height: 200px;
margin: 0 2px 2px 0;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
width: 312px;
}

article .post-info {
display: none;
left: 50%;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
z-index: 100;
}

article .post-info h1 {
line-height: 1.4;
font-size: 20px;
font-size: 2rem;
}

article .post-info a {
color: #FFF;
}

article .post-info span {
font-style: italic;
}

article .post-info a {
color: #FFF;
}

article > img {
width: 100%;
}

.updated:not(.published) {
display: none;
}
```

Edit: Here's a fiddle I created: http://jsfiddle.net/jaL5bd3z/1/

Comment: Why the downvote? I tried to explain the best way I know how. If I left something out, please let me know instead of just downvoting.

Comment: Does it work if you change it to `.on("click", function() {...})`?

Comment: @Alvaro I'm actually trying to change the part where it says `http://link-to-post` so I'm not sure if adding `.on` will work yet. I should have clarified that in the post but I made an edit just now.

Comment: The thing is that if the article is dynamically added (I don't know how WordPress works), then `.click` would not work and you would need to use `.on`

Comment: @Alvaro I'm trying to find the `a` link within. I updated the post above. Can you take a look to see if you understand why I'm having trouble? Also, I tried using `.on`, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are applying the click action to a `div` that only wraps the `h1`. You have two options to fix it:

1. Wrap all the article in the `div`; or
2. Apply the click action to the `article` and not to the `div`.

Something like this:

```
$("article.has-post-thumbnail").click(function() {
     window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
     return false;
 });
```

Comment: Still not working on my end, unfortunately. I went ahead and created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaL5bd3z/1/). There was some info that I didn't include for the sake of brevity but I added everything in there so hopefully it can provide a clearer view of what's going on.

Comment: Sorry, but my solution works on the fiddle with an alert: http://jsfiddle.net/jaL5bd3z/2/

Comment: Actually, it works also with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/jaL5bd3z/3/ notice that I apply the click to the article and not to the post-info

Comment: How do I set the cursor to pointer so that the pointer shows up when I hover over the whole div? I think that's what was confusing me. I tried adding `cursor: pointer` to `.post-info` but it didn't work.

Comment: Add `cursor:pointer` to the styles of the `article` (http://jsfiddle.net/jaL5bd3z/4/)

Answer (score 0):

change the code to this so that entire div is clickable

```
<a href="post-link" rel="bookmark">
    <article id="post-1" class="post-1 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-uncategorized">
    <div class="post-info">
    <h1 class="entry-title">[POST TITLE]</h1>
</div>
    <img width="624" height="400" src="[POST THUMBNAIL]" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image">   
    </article>
</a>
```

because previously there was link for title only so i changed it now to the full article

Comment: Is this valid for HTML5?

Comment: as per me, adding link like this is not be a good practise. I think it will not work perfectly in all browsers. please check this in ie specially after implementing this.

Comment: It is valid as long as you don't have any interactive item (another link or button) in the section. Personally not my favorite, but something like this could work and is valid HTML5

Comment: ya i know @AlvaroMontoro but the question was Make entire div clickable for WordPress posts, not just the title

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes Sorry, I was replying to other comment. I'm ok with your solution.